# Conversation list using one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_messages` (
  `userMessageId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userMessageFrom` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL,
  `userMessageTo` BIGINT(19) NOT NULL,
  `userMessageFromRead` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `userMessageToRead` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `userMessageFromDeleted` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `userMessageToDeleted` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `userMessageContent` TEXT(5000) NULL,
  `userCreated` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  INDEX `fk_users_messages_users1_idx` (`userMessageFrom` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_messages_users2_idx` (`userMessageTo` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`userMessageId`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `userMessageId_UNIQUE` (`userMessageId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_messages_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userMessageFrom`)
    REFERENCES `typinggame`.`users` (`userUniqueId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_messages_users2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userMessageTo`)
    REFERENCES `typinggame`.`users` (`userUniqueId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I am trying to get a conversation list such as:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/fCz8fa24RWyAoOXwRXfqFw.png (taken from another stackoverflow post I was looking at)

And I've tried attempting to use UNION though I'm not too familiar with the use of it, but no matter what happens I can either make it so it only shows messages that the user has sent or vice versa. Or it will show all the results, where I just want a conversation list.

There was a couple threads using `CASE` but I was not able to replicate the same result.

This is my code

```
SELECT 
                userMessageId,
                u1.userUniqueId AS userMessageFrom,
                u2.userUniqueId AS userMessageTo,
                u1.userName AS userMessageFromName,
                u2.userName AS userMessageToName,
                u1.userEnum AS userMessageFromEnum,
                u2.userEnum AS userMessageToEnum,
                u1.userAvatar AS userMessageFromAvatar,
                u2.userAvatar AS userMessageToAvatar,
                userMessageTo,
                userMessageFrom,
                userMessageToRead,
                userMessageFromRead,
                userMessageToDeleted,
                userMessageFromDeleted,
                userMessageContent,
                userMessageId
            FROM
                users_messages
            INNER JOIN 
                users AS u1 ON u1.userUniqueId = userMessageFrom
            INNER JOIN
                users AS u2 ON u2.userUniqueId = userMessageTo
            WHERE
                userMessageFrom != ? AND userMessageTo = ? AND userMessageToDeleted = 0 OR 
                userMessageFrom = ? AND userMessageTo != ? AND userMessageToDeleted = 0
            ORDER BY
                userMessageId DESC
```

Edit: UNION

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    u.userUniqueId AS userUniqueId,
    u.userName AS userName,
    u.userEnum AS userEnum,
    u.userAvatar AS userAvatar,
    userMessageTo,
    userMessageFrom,
    userMessageToRead,
    userMessageFromRead,
    userMessageToDeleted,
    userMessageFromDeleted,
    userMessageContent,
    userMessageId
FROM
    users_messages
JOIN 
    users AS u ON u.userUniqueId = userMessageTo
WHERE
    userMessageFrom = ? AND userMessageToDeleted = 0

UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.userUniqueId AS userUniqueId,
    u.userName AS userName,
    u.userEnum AS userEnum,
    u.userAvatar AS userAvatar,
    userMessageTo,
    userMessageFrom,
    userMessageToRead,
    userMessageFromRead,
    userMessageToDeleted,
    userMessageFromDeleted,
    userMessageContent,
    userMessageId
FROM
    users_messages
JOIN 
    users AS u ON u.userUniqueId = userMessageFrom
WHERE
    userMessageTo = ? AND userMessageToDeleted = 0
```

Comment: Your code does not contain union, so it is hard to say where you was wrong. But you was on the right way, because you need to convert columns (from, to) to rows

Comment: I deleted the UNION code and reverted it to what I have now.

Comment: So you need a union from column with to column and then join them to user info

Comment: I added the UNION code I was trying out, but it still returns duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Technically `UNION` cannot return duplicates because it works this way, but I think you mean you have duplicated data by subset of columns. So yes, `UNION` will not help you, you need to aggregate "another" columns by the columns you consider as identifying.

Assuming you need something like you can see in almost all messengers, here's the script with comments. And [here is an example with sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b15a257e8d3490143acb00aea9d0cdc1).
Script returns all conversations for each user, so to get it for single one you need to filter by userId.

1. Transpose `from` and `to` columns in one column to find the last message for user.
2. Get max messageId (it is incrementing, so it will be last) by each thread, i.e. `GROUP BY` each `partyUserId`.
3. Get message and user info by join with messages and users. For messages it also can be implemented in the second step by using `ROW_NUMBER()` function with partition by `partyUserId` and order by timestamp, then select only rownumber = 1. Added this variant as commented part.
4. Calculate status columns on info you get from last message.

```
with transpose as (
  /*Inbound messages to user*/
  select
    userMessageTo as userId,
    userMessageFrom as partyUserId,
    userMessageId as msgId,
    userCreated as createdOn
    /*,
      --Can be added for row_number variant
    userMessageContent,
    userMessageToRead
    */
  from users_messages
  /*that is not deleted at his side*/
  where userMessageToDeleted = 0
  
  union
  
  /*Outbound messages from user*/
  select
    userMessageFrom as userId,
    userMessageTo as partyUserId,
    userMessageId as msgId,
    userCreated as createdOn
    /*,
      --Can be added for row_number variant
    userMessageContent,
    userMessageToRead
    */
  from users_messages
  /*that user has not deleted*/
  where userMessageFromDeleted = 0
)
, last_msg as (
  select
    userId,
    partyUserId,
    max(msgId) as lastMsgId,
    max(createdOn) as lastMsgDate
  from transpose
/*  where userId = ?*/
  group by
    userId,
    partyUserId
  order by lastMsgDate desc
  /*To show only top messages*/
  limit 30
)
/*Or in this way
, last_msg_with_info as (
  select *
  from (
    select t.*,
      row_number()
        over(
          partition by userId, partyUserId
          order by createdOn desc
        ) as rn
    from transpose
--    where userId = ?
  ) as rn_tab
  where rn = 1
)*/

/*Build conversation list with content of last message in thread*/
select
  lm.userId,
  lm.partyUserId as conversationWithId,
  lm.lastMsgDate as lastMsgDate,
  m.userMessageContent as lastMsgText,
  case
    when lm.userId = m.userMessageFrom
    then 'Sent'
    else 'Received'
  end as LastMsgDirection,
  /*If user sent message, then no need to check. Else check if he already read it*/
  case
    when lm.userId = m.userMessageFrom
    then 0
    else 1 - m.userMessageToRead
  end as hasUnreadMsgFlag,
  /*If user has sent the message, then check if receiver user has read it*/
  case
    when lm.userId = m.userMessageFrom
    then m.userMessageToRead
    else 0
  end as receiverReadFlag,
  u.userName as conversationWithName,
  u.userEnum as conversationWithEnum,
  u.userAvatar as conversationWithAvatar
from last_msg as lm
  join users_messages as m
    on lm.lastMsgId = m.userMessageId
  join users as u
    on lm.partyUserId = u.userUniqueId
order by userId, lastMsgDate
```

Performance of this script is another question. Maybe it would be better to implement another model (with threadId) to get last message without pivot (and in some cases without aggregation).